# JS React Native указание типов аргументов функции

Tags: типы-данных, react-native

Есть функция, возвращающая объект:

```
const Data = (arg0: string, arg1: number) => {
    return {arg0: arg0, arg1: arg1}
};
```

Этот объект передаётся в другую функцию:

```
setData(Data("0", 1));
```

Правильно ли указывать в конструкторе `setData` тип аргумента таким образом:

```
const setData = (data: Data) => {...}
```

Или это говорит лишь о том, что передаётся сама функция, а не её результат?

Comment: Может быть это TypeScript?

Comment: это React Native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, таким образом указывать тип неправильно, передаваемый объект не является объектом типа Data.

Нужно как-то так:

```
class Data {
  arg0: string;
  arg1: number;
  constructor(arg0: string, arg1: number) {
    this.arg0 = arg0;
    this.arg1 = arg1;
  }
}
const setData = (data: Data) => {...}

setData(new Data('answer', 42));
```

Comment: Замечательно, спасибо! А можно ещё вопрос насчёт перечислений: `const Enum = Object.freeze({type0: 'type0', type1: 'type1'});` передавать как `enum: Enum`, или может быть `enum: Enum[any]`?

Comment: Enum всего лишь имя константы, это неверно. [Создайте новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript - не типизированный язык.

Так что нет, тип аргумента указывать неправильно.

Ваш синтаксис вызывает у моего интерпретатора

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Comment: у меня такого не происходит, код работает и более того в WebStorm в автокомплите справа от названия функции высвечивается `[Data] data`